# php get max key from same value

Tags: php, arrays, key, max

How can I get max key from same value?

Example:

```
 1 => 32
 2 => 32
 3 => 32
 4 => 5
 5 => 5
 6 => 11
 7 => 11
```

Result:

```
 3 => 32
 5 => 5
 7 => 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming values are all integer

```
$array = [
  1 => 32,
  2 => 32,
  3 => 32,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 5,
  6 => 11,
  7 => 11,
];

$result = array_flip(array_flip($array));
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
krsort($array);
ksort(array_unique($array);
```